# Incrementar em um campo e Decrementar em outro- JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou num projeto em que, vários `input` *spinners* ao incrementar em um campo ele decrementar em outro.

Exemplo: No 1º campo eu tenho o valor 2. No 2º campo eu tenho o valor 4. Ao clicar para decrementar no 1º campo ele passará o valor subtraído para o 2º campo ficando com os valores 1 e 5 respectivamente.

```js
function id(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function menos(id_qnt) {
  var qnt = parseInt(id(id_qnt).value);
  if (qnt > 0)
    id(id_qnt).value = qnt - 1;
}

function mais(id_qnt) {
  id(id_qnt).value = parseInt(id(id_qnt).value) + 1;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade1" value="0" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais( 'quantidade1' )">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="menos( 'quantidade1' )">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade2" value="0" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais( 'quantidade2' )">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="menos( 'quantidade2' )">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade3" value="0" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais( 'quantidade3' )">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="menos( 'quantidade3' )">
</form>
```

Achei esse código de amostra

Comment: Isso é programação Client Side correto? ou seja do lado do Cliente, não precisa do servidor correto? Tem como colocar na sua pergunta o exemplo que tentou?

Comment: Você está utilizando um input type="number"?

Comment: Isso parece ser um problema de JavaScript, então Laravel não entra na roda. Sendo JavaScript interagindo com o HTML, parece-me que você já possui o HTML feito, então, por favor, adicione o código na pergunta.

Comment: Isso. Estou utilizando o laravel 5.5.

Comment: você vai ter mais de dois campos?

Comment: No seu caso tem 3 como seria a lógica?

Comment: No caso, teria 5 campos. Mas com 2 campos fica mais facil entender a lógica.

Comment: pera um pouco se a sua regra é 5 campos a pergunta também precisa ser, porque: o que você pretende como isso funciona? entendeu!

Comment: Entendi Virgilio. Mas a regra de négocio com 2 campos já serve. O resto é só replicar.

Comment: Então me explica se eu clica no quinto input pra onde vai o resultado?

Comment: No último input ele vai estar desabilitado. Isso já tenho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente é só colocar na função do `menos` quem será agraciado com mais um, exemplo:

```js
function id(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function menos(id_qnt, id_add_qnt) {
  var qnt = parseInt(id(id_qnt).value);
  if (qnt > 0) {
    id(id_qnt).value = qnt - 1;
    id(id_add_qnt).value =
        parseInt(id(id_add_qnt).value) + 1;
  }
}

function mais(id_qnt) {
  id(id_qnt).value = parseInt(id(id_qnt).value) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade1" value="0" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais( 'quantidade1' )">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="menos( 'quantidade1' ,'quantidade2')">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade2" value="0" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais( 'quantidade2' )">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="menos( 'quantidade2' ,'quantidade3')">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade3" value="0" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais( 'quantidade3' )">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="menos( 'quantidade3' ,'quantidade1')">
</div>
```

pelo menos a lógica inicial pelos comentários.

Comment: @Kelvin.Almeida deu certo?

Comment: Ajudou bastante amigo. Muito obrigado!